# How to get username of last logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve the username of the last logged in user after they log out, and this should be achieved using ASP.NET MVC.

Also I don't want to go back whenever the user presses back button of the browser. For that I am using the following code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

The problem is if I use this I clear all the data and then cannot retrieve the username.

Comment: you'd have to save it somewhere else first before clearing the login session, and then retrieve it later when you want to look at it - just like any other piece of data you want to persist. Also do you mean the last user who logged in on that browser, or the last user from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Since the code in your question is related to caching, I'm assuming you want to display the username (and maybe other user information) in the browser after the user has logged out. This is not really a browser-caching problem, it's a server-state problem, which is the direction suggested in the comment from ADyson.

You need to dissociate the user information you provide in the browser from the login status. In other words, change your login process so that the user identity is still known, and "logged in" or "not logged in" is just a "status" associated with each user's identity. Whether the user is logged in or not, you still know who they are after their original login.

Probably the easiest approach is to track that user identity with data stored in a cookie so that you don't need to burden your server with the overhead of storing session state between calls. It could be as simple as storing the database user table's primary key. (Obviously, you shouldn't use this to access sensitive information for logged-out users since this simple approach could be subject to forgery, but username is not typically considered protected information.)